# Error: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to Asp.Net and now I'm facing this problem. I've tried many way as possible I get from google and here. But I still cannot find a solution for this. I've tried to change the Data Source to 127.0.0.1, but I still get the same error. It actually works to connect to database when I'm using **MySql.Data.MySqlClient**. But fail when I'm using **System.Data.SqlClient**
Can you all help me? Thank you very much.

Code Behind:

```
private DataTable GetData(string query)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnStringSql"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {           
                using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmds.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmds.Connection = cons;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmds;
                        **sda.Fill(dt);** //Error occurs here
                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }
```

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebAppConnStringSql"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=vbsite;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

The Error:
*An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*
[SqlException was unhandled by user code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbwtU.jpg)

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Either your database connection is wrong or the server is down and you don't have access to it

Comment: But when I use MySql.Data.MySqlClient to connect to the server. It's ok and no problem. Database connection should not be the problem as I've written the correct information?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing a project in localhost. By using visual studio and wampserver's phpmyadmin mysql database

Comment: you want to connect to mySQL Database?

Comment: Yea. Want to get data from database. So must set connection to there.

Comment: Well, System.Data.SqlClient is for connecting to MS SQLServer. You need [MySql Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/)

Comment: you want to connect to Microsoft SQL Server or MYSQL?

Comment: Have you followed the MySQL Connector documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You should open connection `SqlConnection.Open()`:

```
using (SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection(constr))
{           
   cons.Open();
   using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(query))
   {                   
      using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
      {
         cmds.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmds.Connection = cons;
         sda.SelectCommand = cmds;
         **sda.Fill(dt);** //Error occurs here
      }
   }
   return dt;
}
```

Comment: Yes I've tired this too. And what I get is the same error occurs at the cons.Open() row.

Comment: @StudentABC try to set IntegratedSecurity to false in your connection string.
<add name="WebAppConnStringSql"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=vbsite;Integrated Security=False"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Still the same error. Tried with and without cons.Open() plus Integrated Security=False . Still same error.